# how to google APIs for creating events on google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

anybody know how to create and event on Google calendar using calendars api?

my users connect to my site using Google , I got a permission from them to write in their calendars then when user attend event on my site i need to crate an event on his/her calendar on gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the full google calendar api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_javascript